# Server software complains it is already running when launched over RD

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services

The server software needs to be accessed by remote users. When one user is logged in, the other user cannot launch the software as it complains it is "already active" (running for another user).

My client said that this used to work [for multiple users running it at the same time], but not any more.

I looked at the CAL manager and there was some error but seemed irrelevant to the problem I had. There are 5 CAL licenses assigned to various users which login remotely.

I am a bit of a noob with Windows, so apologies if this is simple and am asking a duplicate question (i searched a lot but cannot find anything relevant!).

Is running same software simultaneously by different (remote) users even possible or do I need to find an alternative solution?

Comment: `Is running same software simultaneously by different (remote) users even possible` - Of course it is, but not every application runs in an RDS environment. If the application in question checks for running instances of itself and prevents running more than one instance then that's an issue with the software. It has nothing to do with Windows and it has nothing to do with your Windows CAL's or your RDS CAL's. You need to speak to the software vendor about this and get their guidance and assistance.

Comment: @joeqwerty I was under the impression that CAL gives you a license to access the server by different people at the same time. It might've been misleading from my client. Thank you

Comment: It does, but it doesn't have anything to do with your application.

Comment: Hmm right so in case there's an error with the CAL would the software stop working for simultaneous users?

Comment: Again, this doesn't have anything to do with your Windows or RDS CAL's. This is a problem with the specific application. Windows and RDS CAL's don't have any bearing on or control of the applications on your RDS server. If the application won't run multiple instances then that is an issue with the application. You need to contact the application vendor and get their assistance.